# Create a custom data view on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, view, custom, data-view-web-part

I'm looking for a way for to create a custom data view on SharePoint. The default SharePoint data view is in columns, for example, exist a way for creating a data view that transforms the columns in rows?
For example:
Default SharePoint view:

```
 Project Name | Start date | End Date
```

My custom data view:

```
Project Name.

Start Date.

End Date
```

---

I'm starting to use SharePoint designer 2013, but I don't know if SPD 2013 can create a custom data view in the form that I need
Thanks for read me, and excuse me for my English

Answer (score 0):

Based on your required customization, I think no need to use SharePoint designer or write any CSS style.

Just you need to modify your view to Show `Style` as **Boxed No Label** as shown below.

[image]

**[OutPut]**

[image]

Comment: Please set it as answer it's the true right beside my answer :)